# Como crear Ventana Tkinter sin barra de comandos

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

quisiera abrir una ventana, sin los botones ni el titulo y alli desplegar un menú, he probado overrideredirect(True), pero no me aparece la linea de menú, probe con -fullscreen','true' como lo suguiere https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529600/remove-titlebar-without-overrideredirect-using-tkinter y si funciona, me aparece el menú sin la barra de comando tkinter, pero me maximiza la ventana y no consigo que lo haga en la ventana que he definido, acá dejo mi código a ver si me pueden ayudar, orientar, Gracias de antemano.

Acá defino ventana, como pueden observar en la lineas de comentario he probado varia opciones.

```
   try:
        self.tree3.item(self.tree3.selection())['values'][0]
    except IndexError as e:
        messagebox.showinfo("A T E N C I O N ! ! !", "Selecciones una FECHA, por favor!")
        return
    self.windows_fx_consulta = Toplevel()
    self.windows_fx_consulta.transient(self.windows_consulta1)
    self.windows_fx_consulta.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    self.windows_fx_consulta.resizable(0,0)
    #   Medidas del Geometry ("ancho x alto + columna + fila")
    self.windows_fx_consulta.geometry("560x258+254+305")
    self.windows_fx_consulta.wm_attributes('-fullscreen','true')
    #self.windows_fx_consulta.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.on_exit) # Invalidar x y mandar a función con mensaje 
    #fondo = tk.Label(self.windows_fx_consulta, image=self.photo_consulta2, background="ivory2")
    #fondo = tk.Label(self.windows_fx_consulta, background="SkyBlue3")
    #fondo.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    self.rx_tipo=''
    #self.windows_fx_consulta.update_idletasks()
    #self.windows_fx_consulta.overrideredirect(True)
    self.menufx()
```

Creo el menú

```
# Crear el menu principal
def menufx(self):
    Label(self.windows_fx_consulta, text = 'Use menú para escoger RX', background='navy', foreground = 'LightSkyBlue3', 
        font = ('arial', 20, 'bold')).place(x =100, y = 100)
  
    menubarra = Menu(self.windows_fx_consulta)
    # Crea un menu desplegable y lo agrega al menu barra
    menufx = Menu(menubarra, tearoff=0)
    menubarra.add_cascade(label="RX Aerea", menu=menufx)
    menufx.add_command(label="RX Actual", command=self.fx_actual, foreground = 'navy', background="LightSkyBlue3", font = ('arial', 14, 'bold'))
    menufx.add_command(label="Rx Auto - Refracción", command=self.fx_auto, foreground = 'navy', background="LightSkyBlue3", font = ('arial', 14, 'bold'))
    menufx.add_command(label="Rx Subjetivo", command=self.fx_suge, foreground = 'navy', background="LightSkyBlue3", font = ('arial', 14, 'bold'))
    #menufx.add_separator()
    menudoctor = Menu(menubarra, tearoff=0)
    menubarra.add_cascade(label="RX Lente de Contacto", menu=menudoctor)
    menudoctor.add_command(label="Rx Prueba", command=self.hola, foreground = 'navy', background="LightSkyBlue3", font = ('arial', 14, 'bold'))
    menudoctor.add_command(label="Rx Definitivo", command=self.hola, foreground = 'navy', background="LightSkyBlue3", font = ('arial', 14, 'bold'))
    menufx1 = Menu(menubarra, tearoff=0)
    menubarra.add_cascade(label="Volver al Menú Consulta", menu=menufx1)
    menufx1.add_command(label="Volver...", command=lambda : self.windows_fx_consulta.destroy(), foreground = 'navy', background="LightSkyBlue3", font = ('arial', 14, 'bold'))
    # Mostrar el menu
    self.windows_fx_consulta.config(menu=menubarra)
```

Comment: No es tan fácil como parece. Tk no da ningún método para poder tener una ventana overrideredirect=True con integración en la barra de herramientas. No tienes otra opción que pelearte con el administrador de ventanas. Hay ejemplos de como medio hacerlo para windows: " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621671/trouble-making-a-custom-title-bar-in-tkinter "," https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123663/make-tkinter-window-appear-in-the-taskbar "," https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786337/tkinter-windows-how-to-view-window-in-windows-task-bar-which-has-no-title-bar

Comment: Muchas Gracias por ayudarme, voy a revizar los link para documentarme, agradecido